# Velocity of a 3D point in a frame sequence

Tags: matlab, 3d, frames

I want to find the velocity of a point p(x,y,z) in 3D space in the terms of frame sequence.
I found that velocity is given as velocity=distance/framerate, where distance=sqrt(x^2+y^2)
for 2 dimensions

My question is if the same is valid for 3D- distance=sqrt(x^2+y^2+z^2) or do i have to add angular velocity at my final result in order to define the velocity of an object??

I use matlab and the object that i refer is a human skeleton(motion tracking).Furthermore the point p is referring in a joint of the the skeleton for the frame sequence.
For example the head trajectory for 90 frames.

Any response whould be helpful!!

Comment: I don't think you need an additional velocity component. After all, you are looking at the direct distance between two points - and not the distance in each of the coordinate directions. I'd say it's vector math. If you look at dx, dy, dz individually, you'll get the velocities in the x, y and z direction. If you look at the total distance form 1->2 you'll get the total velocity.

Comment: Thank you for your response Schorsch.  Basically i want to define if a joint has a feature that contains velocity above a threshold.For example wrist moves from the hip to the head,but the movement can be sideways or from the front(rotate).Furthermore do i have to check velocities of x y z individually or the total velocity will be fine?thank you in advance for any response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instantaneous velocity of a *point* in 3D space can be found from the linear distance it moves between frames, as you wrote: distance=sqrt(x^2+y^2+z^2). If the point is moving along some arc, it could *instead* be expressed as an equivalent angular velocity about some point, but you would not *add* an angular velocity component to the linear component: they would be two alternate ways of expressing the same instantaneous velocity.

If you did express the motion as an angular velocity about a point, this could then be converted back to an instantaneous linear velocity.

Comment: Thank you pancake.I want the linear velocity so i believe i have the righr results.